# How to store json data based on another field data in different arrays

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a json array like this.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "date": "2020-02-21",
    "status": "present",
    "studentid": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "date": "2020-02-24",
    "status": "present",
    "studentid": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "date": "2020-02-25",
    "status": "absent",
    "studentid": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "date": "2020-02-26",
    "status": "absent",
    "studentid": "1"
  }
]
```

I can store the date by using this code snippet

```
if (data instanceof Array) {

                  this.date=data.map(ele => ele.date);
              }
```

How to store the dates in two arrays based on absent and present conditions.That is i want to store date_present in one array and date_absent in another array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Map function to iterate and check the status of each element

```
var present = [];
    var absent = [];
    data.map(ele => {
      ele.status === "absent" ? absent.push(ele) : present.push(ele);
    });
```

Comment: I have kept changedetectionStratergy as default.So do i need to change it to onPush

Comment: yes . inside the onPush method , keep this code so that the arrays are generated at each push

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` to loop through the array and push the object to separate arrays

```
var date_present = [];
var date_absent = [];

data.forEach(ele => {
   if(ele.status ===  "present"){
    date_present.push(ele)
  }
   else if(ele.status ===  "absent"){
    date_absent.push(ele)
  }
});
```

Comment: I have kept changedetectionStratergy as default.So do i need to change it to onPush

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var date_present = [];
var date_absent = [];

date_present = data.filter(item => item.status ===  "present")
date_absent = data.filter(item => item.status ===  "absent")
```

Comment: how can i get dates .it will store the whole content of data rigt